# Does the extra effect in Scavenging lead to 2 discards?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The Scavenging Crossfire card says

> At the start of each turn, the current runner randomly discards 1
>   card. Then for each of their roles, that runner can return a card from
>   their discard to their hand that has a color that matches that role
>   color.

Then, the additional effect for crossfire discard piles of 3 or more says

> Instead, that runner randomly discards 1 card after returning cards

This wording confuses me.  Do I randomly discard, then return cards for each role, then discard again?  The "Instead" in the wording implies that the second discard is in place of doing something after the card returning, but the original text doesn't do anything after the card returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only discard one card as that is all the crossfire rule calls for. If you notice it specifies how many cards to draw based on the game setup and it specifies how many to discard under all game setups.

For the normal version you discard then draw meaning you won't discard what you will draw. Also you can draw the card you just discarded.

For the hard version you draw then discard meaning you can discard a card you just drew.

Comment: I am flustered by the wording. I just realized that perhaps the harder version is saying that instead of returning cards after discarding you discard after returning (ie do not discard before returning cards in the latter case). Could that be the proper reading of it?

Comment: @Joey I just edited my answer, hope it makes more sense.